# How do I add a Yes/No parameter in Telerik report for conditional formatting to make detail section visible True or False?

Tags: parameters, visible, telerik-reporting

I want to add a parameter in a Telerik report that is not part of the datasource for the report but will determine whether the user wants to see the detail section or not when the report runs.  The two selections in the parameter would be Yes or No.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way was to add a report checkbox that would make the detail section visibility true or false.